# Next.js Middleware not working after deploy in firebase hosting

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I deploy my Next.js application to Firebase to serve dynamic content with the help of this [repo](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-framework-tools/). This is repo is suggested by [What's new in Firebase](https://youtu.be/i0VNBvCqpgI?t=420) official video from firebase team.

My middleware work fine in local but not after deploy. How to fix ?

in `middleware.ts`

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request) {
  const url = request.nextUrl.clone();
  if (url.pathname === "/") {
    url.pathname = "/home";
    return NextResponse.redirect(url);
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/", "/dashboard/:path*", "/login/:path*"],
  api: {
    externalResolver: true,
  },
};
```

and in `firebase.json`

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "cleanUrls": true
  }
}
```

Comment: what error(s) you are getting?

Comment: @SathiAiswarya index page is not redirecting to '/home'. you can see in middleware.ts

Comment: Have a look at this stackoverflow link(https://stackoverflow.com/a/66425095/18265638)

Comment: still not working

Comment: can you check this [link] once? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65881573/18265638

Comment: @SathiAiswarya we can deploy dynamic next js website to firebase hosting with help of Firebase function. I have given link of video of 'whats new in firebase', they justify it. After deployment website work fine but middleware not.

Comment: To get same problem you have to just follow steps given in above repo(link is given above). And add middleware.